# Formatting DateTable Date Column When Importing to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, date, csv, filehelpers

I'm currently using the `FileHelpers` package to import a `DataTable` of information into my `MySQL` database. After running my program the data in the database looks like this;

[image]

The format of the MySQL Column is `DATETIME`. These are the methods I'm currently using, you can see that I've tried to format the column correctly already;

**Contacts**

```
    private void Contacts()
    {
        try {
            using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(dbfConstr))
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                var dbfCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT ct_id, ct_cmpid, ct_empid,
                ct_pplid, ct_cntid, ct_pplnm, ct_date, ct_time, ct_type, ct_doneby, ct_desc
                FROM contacts", dbfCon);
                var dTable = new DataTable();
                var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbfCmd);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                WriteDateTimeToCSV(dTable, "contacts");
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**WriteDateTimeToCSV**

This method simply trims the data down, then uses the rest;

```
    public void WriteDateTimeToCSV(DataTable dataTable, string mySqlTable)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Trim the DataTable
        dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList()
        .ForEach(row =>
        {
            var cellList = row.ItemArray.ToList();
            row.ItemArray = cellList.Select(x => x.ToString().Trim()).ToArray();
        });

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {   
            // Used to remove carriage returns
            if (row[10].ToString().Contains("\r\n"))
            {
                row[10] = row[10].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "*?*!");
            }
        CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(dataTable, @"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\filehelpers.csv", '|');
        WriteToMySQL(mySqlTable);
    }
```

to write the DataTable to CSV. In CSV format the Date formatting looks like dd MM YYYY, with no `-` between any of the days/months/years. I believe that this is what is confusing the formatting in the MySQL Database.

I haven't had much experience with `FileHelpers` before, is it that package that is causing the formatting to be incorrect?

**EDIT:** I've tried using this;

`row[6] = ((DateTime)row[6]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

but when I print out `row[6]` I still have the exact same problem.

Comment: Are the dates in a correct format from the DataTable? and only wrong when importing to the database?

Comment: @Bayeni No the dates aren't in the correct format in the DataTable, they look like this in the DataTable: `Fri 02 08 1996 0002 08 1996 00:00:00` for example. I can't find a way to format the `SELECT` statement I'm using in `OleDB` either.

Comment: Last question :) are you reading this data from microsoft access database?

Comment: @Bayeni Visual Fox Pro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `((DateTime)row[6]).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")`

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried so far in my edit. No luck so far!

Comment: I've changed it to DATE but still no luck

Comment: What type has row[6] before the cast?